# How to change this text input text to password input? Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have this  text input on my laravel project and i want to change it for password input with asterisks

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('user-password','Password') }}
                {{ Form::text('password',$users->home_password,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

**EDIT**

when i change it as the guy below suggested/answered i get this error

> Illegal string offset 'name'

thats why i posted this question but forgot to write it.
Is it laravel problem or something else ?

Comment: `{{ Form::password( ... ) }}`

Comment: i tried that but doesnt work...:S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `text` use `password`:

```
{{ Form::password('user-password') }}
```

Note: Here is an example of a general form of this line:

```
{{ Form::password('password_confirmation',array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Re-type Password', 'autocomplete'=>'off')) }}
```

Comment: Illegal string offset 'name'  i get this error thats why i posted this question

Comment: I have updated the code. I know your intention with `Password` is for it to act as a placeholder but consider using the `placeholder` attribute instead.

Comment: The issue is with the `-`; use `_`instead.

Comment: sorry but i think there is a problem cause if i do it your way i dont the password in the box for the specific user @PeterKA

Comment: Please bear in mind that once you replace the `-` with `_` you have do the same in the code that retrieves the input values .... example `$password = Input::get('user_password');`

Comment: I undertood what u mean u are right but i dont need the save input i know your code what it does im in the edit blade i want to show the password of the specific user for example if user with id = 3 has 1234 password to be shown as **** in a box , ur code is for the creation of user, i understand that thx i needed that also but i need exactly asterisk as the password of the user ! hope u understood now